# Angular 6 - Local files (js, css, img) added to assets not seen at run time. How to reference all files at once?

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor

Using Angular 6 and Angular CLI 6, 
I added a folder **myfolder** which contains many files:

```
src/assets/myfolder
```

**Note:** I also tried:

```
src/myfolder
```

At run time the files are not found/working unless I specify them individually in **angular.json** with:

```
"assets": [
                  "src/assets",
                  "src/favicon.ico"
              ],
    "scripts": [
                   "src/assets/myfolder/myfile1.js",
                   "src/assets/myfolder/myfile2.js",
                   "src/assets/myfolder/myfile3.js",
                   "src/assets/myfolder/mycss.css",
                   "src/assets/myfolder/myImage.img"
               ]
```

While this works, my folder is a CKEditor plugin and containt over 100 files form js,css to images, which all reference each other. It seems there must be a way to add everything without referencing each file individually?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcard should suffice

```
assets: [
      "src/assets/*",
]
```

In the code always use

```
src="assets/..."
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work any more in Angular 6. [Here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/11071) is the discussion about that on Github.

Answer (score 0):

If you use on your html code this

ex: `src="assets/myFolder/logo.png"`

It should be enought

Comment: This dosnt solve the problem, again i have over 100 files in a folder and they all reference each other and normally work, I need to just use one of them for the plugin to work, but the rest of the files are not added to dist unless specified individually.

Answer (score 0):

Adding non-javascript files to "scripts" is not the intended behaviour of Angular CLI.
Instead you can add (s)css files to the "styles" array or import them directly into src/styles.scss

As for images, fonts or any other assets, it should be safe to keep them into src/assets, as long as you reference them by **absolute path** (starting with `/`). For example, in one of your templates you could have something like `<img src="/assets/myfolder/myImage.img"/>`, or in your scss files you could have `.some-class { background-image: url(/assets/myfolder/myImage.img); }`

Comment: Again, this oesnt solve the issue, I have a folder, which is escentially a plugin for CKEditor, it contains everything and all files use each other, i can not split that all up and reference each file in scripts.

Comment: Your use case isn't very clear for me - it sounds like you're trying to make Angular serve some standalone widgets hosted in the assets folder. This may conflict with how Angular's routing interprets URL paths, but I can't tell what's wrong without more information about your project's architecture.